# pivoting result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    PhaseId,    
    COUNT(JoinId)
FROM Joins
GROUP BY
    PhaseId
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   143
2   65
3   86
```

I usually pivot the result by using the case technique for each column, but now I'm trying to use the PIVOT statement unsuccessfully. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx does not help?

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far, even if it isn't working.

Comment: @MK. No, it doesn't, I can't figure out how to use the group by and count in that example and I can't find good examples using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like there are many examples out there, but `PIVOT` is hard to wrap your head around, so:

```
SELECT *
FROM   
 ( SELECT PhaseId,JoinID
   FROM YourTable
  ) AS T1
PIVOT (COUNT(JoinID) FOR PhaseId IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS T2
```